# Themes for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: themes

I want to download themes for ubuntu 14.04, but I was confused because in the folder /usr/share/themes there are 18 folder. And the only folder that contains gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, metacity-1, unity, and one file 'index.theme' that can be used for theme.

So I had to have a theme with gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, metacity-1, unity, and the file 'index.theme'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a lot of themes from [http://gnome-looks.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xsortmode=high&page=0&xcontentmode=167)

The safest way is to create a .themes directory in your home for themes and .icons for icon themes.

You can also, but not recommend, extract the archives you download, and move the **correct theme folder** to `/usr/share/themes`
A theme folder consist of elements like `gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, metacity-1, unity, index.theme`

You will need to start the file manager as super user when copying the themes:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

I personally avoid this because you could wrongly and unintentionally delete some important system file.

Install `unity-tweak-tool` from Ubuntu Software Center to change the themes.

Comment: There are many themes in http://gnome-look.org , but what categories I must choose? Gtk-2.0, Gtk-3.0, or Metacity?

Comment: Thx for your answer, themes are in gtk-3.x section ;-)