# Ubuntu themes problem

Tags: themes, budgie

I created this path .local/share/themes and downloaded a theme from github to this path, but can't make ubuntu detect the theme via ravenbar from ubuntu budgie remix distro Im using.

How can I make ravenbar detect the theme, I don't want to gain priviledges and make a usr/share/themes were all other themes are at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Themes for Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468056/themes-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Reviewers, the Ubuntu Budgie distro is off-topic until 17.04 is released.

Answer (score 1):

Te correct path to add and apply themes in user level is just ~/.themes directory (in your home directory). Did you try that?

Comment: Doesn't work, no such file or directory.

Comment: Of course, you must create this directory at first `mkdir ~/.themes` and then you can copy themes into this directory